# custom ban page for homebrew website

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess

I understand how to ban an IPs address from my apache webserver using .htaccess:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.44.201
deny from 224.39.163.12
deny from 172.16.7.92
allow from all
```

I'd like to create a custom "You've been banned" page. How could I do this?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I am *not* trying to create a custom 403 page, as these are used in other instances as well (i.e. failed basic authentication, etc). The closest I have come so far is:

```
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule !^banned$ /banned [NC,L]
```

but this produces an internal server error when the IP is matched, instead of sending the user to /banned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers which suggest an `ErrorDocument` for the 403 code would be the usual way to do this. But since you want to show a different error page if the user is denied access based on IP (as opposed to other reasons), you can use mod_rewrite, as you suspected.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =192.168.44.201 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =224.39.163.12 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =172.16.7.92
RewriteRule !^/banned.html /banned.html [L]
```

P.S. This should go in your virtual host configuration, not an `.htaccess` file, if at all possible. If you don't have access to the virtual host configuration file, you could put it in a `.htaccess` file, but remove the leading slash from the `RewriteRule` pattern (so `!^/banned.html` becomes `!^banned.html`).

Comment: Thank you, it was that leading slash that was messing with my internal server errors. I'm running into another problem though - I already have a rewrite rule in my htaccess file, and I'm getting internal server errors if i don't comment out the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's hard to tell without seeing what the first rewrite rule is.

Answer (score 2):

You use an `ErrorDocument` directive. People that are denied access are sent a 403 header, so:

```
ErrorDocument 403 banned.html
```

will redirect banned people to `banned.html`

---

<s>Edit: The other alternative is to drop the mod_access stuff altogether, and use an IP-based rewrite rule (as mentioned in the question).  It should just be:</s>

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 192.168.44.201 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 224.39.163.12 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 172.16.7.92
RewrulteRule .* banned.html [L]
```

---

Edit 2: David beat me to an almost identical answer; I think [his way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339004/custom-ban-page-for-homebrew-website/3339102#3339102) is what you want

Comment: While this is indeed useful, it would result in "banned" messages every time someone hits a 403 error

Comment: @Mala Well...yes, isn't that the point? Do you serve 403 error codes for situations besides this one?

Comment: if file permissions are set for a user not to be able to read a document, or fails basic authentication, he should get a 403 error. However, he won't be banned

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /banned.html
```

change /banned.html to whatever path/to/filename you want.